# Avoid installing optional deps with Yarn

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

In my `yarn.lock` file I have only one reference to momentjs:

```
pikaday@^1.6.0:
  version "1.6.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/pikaday/-/pikaday-1.6.1.tgz#b91bcb9b8539cedd8d6d08e4e7465e12095671b0"
  optionalDependencies:
    moment "2.x"
```

I delete all the `node_modules`folder and the `yarn.lock` file, and run `yarn --ignore-optional` but the new `yarn.lock` generated contains the same lines, and it installs `moment` in my node_modules so it gets included in my bundle.

I am running on the yarn version `0.27.5`.

How can avoid to install this dep marked as optional?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Yarn indeed lists all optional dependencies at `yarn.lock`. However, when `--ignore-optional` flag is specified those modules aren't installed into `node_modules/`.